# Raise Windows after release mouse button

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, window

windows raise after press (before release) mouse button in ubuntu. For this reason we can not make drag & drop when two windows are overlap . Is there is any way to do that a window raise when release mouse button? Which package control this behaviour? I like to modify source code so need to know the package name first. please help